# Android Math quiz (Thread manipulation)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, android-dialog

I need to make a math quiz. Here is workflow:

On button click(Start) i need to show a question e.g. 5+5, which stays on screen for 2 seconds after which a dialog i shown asking for result of previous operation. And i need to repeat that for e.g. 5 times. At the end I need to show to user number of correct answers.

I have Java experience but I'm new to Android. I have read various articles and examples regarding Android threading but haven't found solution to this workflow.

As far as I know I cannot block or pause main/UI thread, but the problem is that i should repeat questions for e.g. 5 times and after each one(after 2 sec.) I should pause activity to show Dialog and then go back to showing another question.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is my code for now. The number is shown on screen and after 2 seconds alert dialog is shown asking to enter that number. But the problem is that the application doesn't wait for user input but continues to show new random number an opens new alert dialog every 2 seconds.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);

    handler = new Handler();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(50) + 1));
            createDialog();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
}


 protected void createDialog() {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_answer_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // get user input and set it to result
                            // edit text
                            result.setText(userInput.getText());
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

PS. Also I tried to create separate Activity for dialog and added this line to Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You use event driven programming and timers.  To show the dialog after 2 seconds, the easiest way is to post a runnable to a handler using postDelayed, which will call your runnable in N milliseconds.  Then display the dialog box.

You don't need to pause the activity to show the dialog box, just show it.  Any code that you want to run after the dialog is finished with should be put in the handler for the dialog's ok button.  In other words, your code is called in response to the event of a button being pressed.